# If statements in jquery not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to jQuery. I am trying to create a survey; in the survey each question in in its own div and is revealed by clicking the "Next" button. I just have all divs hidden except for the current div. I'm trying to write the answers to an object as I go to simplify the code. There are questions answered with radio buttons, some text areas, some check boxes, and some selects. Here is my code:

```
$('.next-button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().has('.survey-question-option')) {
    replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().contents('.survey-question-option:checked').val();
  } else if ($(this).parent().has("textarea")) {
    replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().contents("textarea").val();
  }
  console.log(replies);
  $(this).parent().attr('hidden', '');
  $(this).parent().next().removeAttr('hidden');
});
```

I'm logging the Object (replies) to make sure things are working. As the code is currently formulated I get the answers to the first two questions (both of which are radio buttons) added to replies, but the next two objects (textareas) populate as undefined. (`{reason: "bill", wish: "newstart", dislike: undefined, like: undefined}`). I tried formulating the if statement as two separate statements:

```
if ($(this).parent().has('.survey-question-option')) {
  replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().contents('.survey-question-option:checked').val();
};
if ($(this).parent().has("textarea")) {
  replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().contents("textarea").val();
};
```

That returns undefined for the radio buttons, but the contents of the two textareas shows up in the object. (`{reason: undefined, wish: undefined, dislike: "dislike text", like: "like text"}`). In doing some testing on my own I've determined that if the if statement is formulates as if...else if the formula always applies the if statement only, but if it is created with two if statements it skips thew first and goes straight for the second.

My logic is that each Next button is in a div with the responses, so I should be able to look at the parent of the Next button, find the appropriate class, and get the value. And it seems to only work 50% of the time no matter how I formulate it.

**EDIT:** I am attaching the relevant html sections.

```js
$('.next-button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().has('.survey-question-option')) {
    replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().contents('.survey-question-option:checked').val();
  } else if ($(this).parent().has("textarea")) {
    replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().contents("textarea").val();
  }
  console.log(replies);
  $(this).parent().attr('hidden', '');
  $(this).parent().next().removeAttr('hidden');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="survey">
  <div id="reason" class='radio'>
    <p class="survey-question">What is the primary reason you visit the site? </p>
    <input type="radio" id="bill" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="bill">
    <label for="bill" class="survey-question-option-label">To view or pay my bill online</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="outage" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="outage">
    <label for="outage" class="survey-question-option-label">To view or report an outage</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="start" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="start">
    <label for="start" class="survey-question-option-label">To get information about starting or stopping services</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="hours" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="hours">
    <label for="hours" class="survey-question-option-label">To find Frederick Waster's business hours</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="board" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="board">
    <label for="board" class="survey-question-option-label">To get information about Frederick Water's governance or board meetings</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="devel" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="devel">
    <label for="devel" class="survey-question-option-label">To get information about new water or wastewater lines for new development</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="reason" class="survey-question-option" value="other">
    <label for="other" class="survey-question-option-label">Other</label><br>
    <div id="other-fill-reason" class="other-fill" hidden>
      <label for="othertext-reason" class="survey-question-option-label">Please specify: </label>
      <input type="text" class="survey-question-other" id="othertext-reason">
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="next-button" id="reason-next" value="Next">
  </div>

  <div id="wish" class='radio' hidden>
    <p class="survey-question">What do you wish the site did better?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="newstart" name="wish" class="survey-question-option" value="newstart">
    <label for="newstart" class="survey-question-option-label">Allow me to pay deposit while starting new service</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="outinfo" name="wish" class="survey-question-option" value="outinfo">
    <label for="outinfo" class="survey-question-option-label">Provide easier-to-find information about outages</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="startstop" name="wish" class="survey-question-option" value="startstop">
    <label for="startstop" class="survey-question-option-label">Make it easier to start and stop services</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="request" name="wish" class="survey-question-option" value="request">
    <label for="request" class="survey-question-option-label">Make it easier to request maintenance for existing service</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="chat" name="wish" class="survey-question-option" value="chat">
    <label for="chat" class="survey-question-option-label">Let me talk to customer service online</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="other2" name="wish" class="survey-question-option" value="other">
    <label for="other2" class="survey-question-option-label">Other</label><br>
    <div id="other-fill-wish" class="other-fill" hidden>
      <label for="othertext-wish" class="survey-question-option-label">Please specify: </label>
      <input type="text" class="survey-question-other" id="othertext-wish">
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="next-button" id="wish-next" value="Next">
  </div>

  <div id="dislike" class="textbox" hidden>
    <p class="survey-question">What do you dislike about the site?</p>
    <textarea id="dislike-text" class="like-dislike" cols="100" rows="5" maxlength="500" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" class="next-button" id="dislike-next" value="Next">
  </div>
  <div id="like" class="textbox" hidden>
    <p class="survey-question">What do you like about the site?</p>
    <textarea id="like-text" class="like-dislike" cols="100" rows="5" maxlength="500" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" class="next-button" id="like-next" value="Next">
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of code showing how it behaves currently? It would be easier to analyze and test.

Comment: @MihailMinkov Do you mean a snippet of the html?

Comment: `.contents()` doesn't take an argument. Did you mean to use `.children()`?

Comment: @NawedKhan There's no `hasClass` in the code.

Comment: @DannyMcCaslin yes, both html and jquery so that we can test the clicks.

Comment: But inside a snippet it's the code bracket icon inside the text editor, says insert snippet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need to change `.contents` to `.children` or `.find`

Comment: @Barmar `.contents()` does take an argument in the code. I mean, line `$(this).parent().contents('.survey-question-option:checked').val()` actually does find the class that is checked. Just in case, I tried changing all of the `.contents()` to `.children()` and it still has the same issue. In the if/else statement the radio buttons get processed but the text box shows up as undefined.

Comment: @Barmar `.find()` doesn't work either.

Comment: `.has()` doesn't return a boolean, it returns a jQuery object, which is always truthy.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, that explains some of the behavior! So should I run it is `if ( $(this).parent().children() === true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has()` doesn't return a boolean, it returns a jQuery object. Objects are always truthy.

If you want to test whether a selector finds anything, test the length of the result.

```js
$('.next-button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().find('.survey-question-option').length > 0) {
    replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().find('.survey-question-option:checked').val();
  } else if ($(this).parent().find("textarea").length > 0) {
    replies[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).parent().find("textarea").val();
  }
  console.log(replies);
  $(this).parent().attr('hidden', '');
  $(this).parent().next().removeAttr('hidden');
});
```

Comment: That appears to have worked! Out of curiosity, because I'm sure it will help me with the rest of this, why does it not work to just test the existence of something? Why do I have to test for `($(this).parent().find('.survey-question-option').length > 0)` instead of just '($(this).parent().find('.survey-question-option'))`

Comment: Because `.has()` returns a jQuery object. Objects are always truthy.

Comment: I got that part. I mean when I use `find()` why do I have to test for length > 0 instead of just testing if it exists?

Comment: A jQuery object always exists even if the selector doesn't find anything.